# Executing procdump from within application to create dump of application itself

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, procdump

I am trying to get my application (VB.NET compiled against framework .NET 4.0) to write a process dump of itself to help me with debugging.  To this end, I am using Procdump from Sysinternals.

To get started, I simply execute the following code on a click Event (so there should be something recognizable on the call stack):

```
Dim p As New Process
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\procdump.exe"
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-accepteula -ma " & Process.GetCurrentProcess.Id
p.Start()
p.WaitForExit()
p.Dispose()       ' Breakpoint
```

On the last line is also a Breakpoint.

To create a dump, I start the application in debug mode within VS 2010, click a button to get this code to execute, and when it hits the breakpoint I know that the dump has been written.  At this point, I also create another dump file using Visual Studio (Debug -> Save Dump As..).

That leaves me with two dump files of roughly equal size (400 something Mb), one created by Procdump.exe and one created by Visual Studio.  Without touching any of the code that was built, I now open both dump files (with the built code open, I hit Ctrl+O) and specify the debug output folder in the symbol folders option.

Now when I click "Debug with mixed" on the dump created by Visual Studio, I get a call stack (on the main thread) with recognizable method names, and the debugger positions it nicely at the position in the source code, where the breakpoint was.

However, when I click "Debug with mixed" on the dump created by Procdump, the call stack (of the main thread) only contains stuff like clr.dll!6cb34e46(), KERNELBASE.dll!75106a8e() with ntdll.dll!76f07094() at the top.  No recognizable code, and also nothing relevant in the watch.

**Why is that?**  Actually, I was expecting these two dumps to be almost equal (off by a few lines of code only).  *[Has to do with the debugger being attached, see edit below.]*

Note that the symbols were correctly loaded in both cases.  The listings I get in Debug->Windows->Modules show the same symbols to be loaded for both dumps.  Moreover, if I switch to a background thread in both dumps, I get a correct call stack for these (with the values of their variables, and so on) in both dumps.

**EDIT**

I noticed that by executing the application without the debugger attached, I get the expected process dump (i.e., equal to the one captured by Visual Studio, but off by one line).  Problem solved.  But I'm still curious as to why I didn't get that result with the debugger attached.

Answer (score 1):

procdump itself is a debugger. What you are doing is asking it to dump a process that is already being debugged, hence the difference dump file.